# Rails, handling multiple redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, facebooker

I have a program where a gem, facebooker, calls a redirect and in the same action I end up callling a redirect through `redirect_back_or_default`.  My question is:

1. Is there a way to catch the multiple redirect error?  A begin/rescue block doesn't seem to do it.
2. Or, is there a way to check to see if a redirect has already been called so I don't call the next one?

At this point, I don't want to modify the facebooker gem, so what do you feel is the best way to handle this?

Thanks all,
Justin

Answer (score 2):

A look at the source of [ActionController#redirect_to](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L60) helps out:

```
raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body
```

You could rescue the Exception like this (and just leave the log line out):

```
class TesterController < ApplicationController
  #I am redirecting ever to index.html
  def index
   redirect_to '/index.html'

   redirect_to '/tester/index'
  rescue AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
   Rails.logger.info "I redirected two times at least but the user doesn't know"
  end
end
```

or you can test (in my opinion this is **no good practice**) for response_body similar to what the ActionController does:

```
class TesterController < ApplicationController
  def index
   redirect_to '/index.html'

   redirect_to '/tester/index' unless response_body
  end    
end
```